# write query using joins using condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

there arr two tables table1,table2.

table1:

| number | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 1 | steve |
| 1100 | 2 | john |
| 1100 | 2 | jack |

.....
and so on for different numbers

similiarly table2:

| number | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 1 | abraham |
| 1100 | 2 | john |
| 1100 | 2 | jack |

and so on for different numbers...
Expected output:join two tables based on equal number and equal type but on name condition it should print where there is mismatch.for example in above john had type '2' in table 1 and in table 2 also there is john but for type '1' it is mismatch as steve <> abraham.I am doing this query but the output contains rows with jack and john too:

| number | type | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 1 | steve | abraham |
| 1100 | 2 | john | jack |
| 1100 | 2 | jack | john |

here the number of rows in table 1 and table 2 are equal similiarly number of rows for each type in each table are also equal

```
select * from table1,table2 where table1.number=table2.number and table1.type=table2.type and table1.name <> table2.name
```

expected output:

| number | type | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 1 | steve | abraham |

As you can see above I have given the output which I got for my query(it contains jack,John pairs but I don't want them as for type '2' names are same in both tables)but if you see for type '1' names are different in both tables so I want to print them.if names are different in type'2' for both tables I want them too as output but here in example names are same in both tables for type '2'.Can anyone help me..?

Comment: Given an example where the mismatch has multiple rows in one or both of the tables.

Comment: As you can see above I have given the output which I got for my query(it contains jack,John pairs but I don't want them as for type '2' names are same in both tables)but if you see for type '1' names are different in both tables so I want to print them.if names are different in type'2' for both tables I want them too as output but here in example names are same in both tables for type '2'.Can you please help me on this?

Comment: What if there is another row in table2 with `1100,1,bob`? What would be your expected output? The sample data that you posted are not enough to cover all cases.

Comment: Good question but here the number of rows in table 1 and table 2 are equal similiarly number of rows for each type in each table are also equal

Comment: Can you have more than 1 different names? Meaning will there be a need for another column name3 in your desired output?

Comment: No as I said the number of rows are equal for both tables so if there is different name then name1,name2 will be there in output based on join there may be multiples rows but not another column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
SELECT table1.number
    ,table1.type
    ,table1.name
    ,table2.name
FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON 
        table2.number = table1.number AND
        table2.type = table1.type AND
        table1.name NOT IN (SELECT t2.name 
                              FROM table2 t2 
                              WHERE t2.number = table1.number AND 
                                t2.type = table1.type)
```